# Physics.BoxCast From 2D Camera Screenspace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Lately I have started a project on an RTS game and honestly I didn't know I would run into so many difficulties.

The main problem I have right now is that I cannot find a way to project a 2D rectangle into the world, to get the units that are inside my screen rectangle and select them. I have an idea of how I could go about it using Physics.BoxCast but I just can't get my head around calculating it from the camera's rotation, and distance to the ground.

Here is the code I use to create a standard RTS unit rectagle selection tool.

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        mouseStartPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 curMousePos = Input.mousePosition;

        if (!selectionBoxObj.activeSelf)
        {
            selectionBoxObj.SetActive(true);
        }

        float width = curMousePos.x - mouseStartPos.x;
        float height = curMousePos.y - mouseStartPos.y;

        Vector2 selectionCenter = new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2);

        selectionBoxTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(width), Mathf.Abs(height));
        selectionBoxTransform.anchoredPosition = mouseStartPos + selectionCenter;

    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        if (selectionBoxObj.activeSelf)
        {
            selectionBoxObj.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

Now, can someone much smarter than me, help me with converting these coordinates into a BoxCast or similar function?

I know there is an easier way, which is storing every possible unit in a list and then checking their world to screen position, but I do not like that approach as I feel like it is extremely taxing when there are a lot of units which I intend having.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: project a 2D rectangle from the camera's perspective into a 3D collider does not make much sense. You mean project a 2D rectangle into the world, to get the units that are inside your screen rectangle and select them?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Well yes, I tried to explain as simply as I could.

Comment: Is your camera orthogonal or perspective ?

Comment: @derHugo Right now it is in Perspective mode.

Comment: Have you looked at [`RTSSelection`](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SelectionBox)? it's a bit old and only based on positions instead of bounds but I guess it should be easy to adopt that

Comment: @derHugo I haven't tried that yet, thank you.

Comment: @derHugo The actual selecting works great, but still it's not ideal as it uses the method where we store all possible units inside a list and then we loop through all of them to check if they are within the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: @derHugo This was something I wanted to avoid, as I don't think it's an efficient solution for big unit numbers.

Comment: What I would try to do is to find the 4 planes the window selected in the world, properly oriented with the normal looking inside and get the units that are inside the 4 planes. To get the side of a point in a plane is just a dot product. Unity [plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) class. Should be smarter ways no doubt. Just that would be mi first approach

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I never really used Planes so I might have a hard time impleting it into the code.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay for the entire frustrum this is very simple ([`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)) however for a certain Rect of the GameView it would be quite tricky to manually calculate the correct perspectivic frustrum I guess .. it would be easy if the camera was orthogonal because then it would be a simple OverlapBox

Comment: I thought it was for a user rectangle selection, not the frustum. I was not aware of the GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB function, very interesting

Comment: If you are concerned about iterating a large list of elements and doing position comparisons, you could try storing your elements in some kind of spacial partitioning structure, like a KD Tree